# Split a string on a pattern using bash and/or awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I have a file that is formatted like

```
file header string(s)
"section title" : [status]
unknown
text

"next section" : [different_status]
different
amount of

strings
```

I want to break this into sections such as

```
file header string(s)
```

and

```
"section title" : [status]
unknown
text
```

and

```
"next section" : [different_status]
different
amount of

strings
```

though it isn't critical to capture that header string.

As you can see, the pattern I can depend on for splitting is

```
"string in quotes" : [string in square brackets]
```

This delimiting string needs to also be captured.

What is a simple way to do this within a bash script? I predict something in awk will do it, but my awk-fu is weak.

Comment: isn't the "pattern" for "splitting" empty line?

Comment: Not quite. There is no empty line before the first section, and there is an empty line within the last section. The text after the section headings could be pretty much anything, so I can't really depend on anything in there. Technically it is possible that it resemble the section headings, but this is unlikely.

Comment: Check out `man csplit`...

Comment: I ended up using twalberg's suggestion of `csplit` which worked perfectly and simply.

Answer (score 3):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $output = 0;
open my $OUT, '>', "section-$output" or die $!;
while (<>) {
    if (/"[^"]*" : \[[^\]]*\]/) {
        $output++;
        open $OUT, '>', "section-$output" or die $!;
    }
    print {$OUT} $_;
}
```

Comment: This perl method does work, though I would prefer something I can more easily incorporate in a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick in pure Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    [[ "$line" =~ "^\"[^\"]*\" : \[[^]]*\]" ]] && i=$(( ++i ))
    [[ $i > 0 ]] && echo "SECTION_$i: " $line
done < $1
```

Update: improved regex.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a one-liner in `awk`.  Assuming I'm interpreting your diving lines correctly, what about this?

```
awk '/^"[^"]+" : \[[^]]+\]$/ { printf("\n"); } 1' inputfile > outputfile
```

The "1" at the end is a shortcut that says "print the current line".  The condition and expression pair before it will insert the blank if the current line matches the pattern.

You could alternately do the same thing in a `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -r '/^"[^"]+" : \[[^]]+\]$/{x;p;x;}' inputfile > outputfile
```

This uses the magic of sed's "hold space".  You can `man sed` for details of how `x` works.